# I'm a student abroad or I'm a student IN abroad?

Tags: prepositions

Should I say

> I am a student abroad

or

> I am a student **IN** abroad

?

Answer (score 6):

[abroad](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/abroad) is an adverb- you don't need a preposition like **in** to link it to a sentence.

Another example of an adverb is

> I am working **today**

If you used the name of a country, for example **America**, that's a noun and so you do need a preposition:

> I am working **in** America
>
> I am a student **in** America

Comment: And according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abroad), the "a" in "abroad" actually means "in".

Comment: Please come **here**. We are digging a big well *over* **here**. These are two example sentences where *here* is an adverb according to the school of grammar you follow. But one sentence needs a preposition before an adverb and another sentence doesn't need any preposition. So no preposition before adverb is not always true, I guess. There is another example with *abroad* - Who is that student *from* **abroad**? Omitting **from** would be wrong.

Comment: @Man_From_India:  when **abroad** is used after from, it is a noun. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/abroad. **here** can also be a noun, so I suspect that it is a noun in the phrase **over here**.

Comment: @JavaLatte any dictionary reference where it says **here** is a noun?

Comment: Hmmmm though I don't consider *abroad* in *from abroad* as a noun, but there indeed are some use of *abroad* as noun. That's strange. But as far as I know such usage seems odd to the majority of English population. *I like abroad*.

Comment: I think the use of *abroad* as a noun is heavily restricted. And such usage is rare. That's what I can say. Or else why not *he want to go **to** abroad*?

Comment: @Man_From_India, agreed. The only examples of nominal usage are with **from**. It would not be appropriate to use it with **to** because it is not a particular place- it's everywhere except this country. In the same way, you can come **from** outside but you can't go **to** outside.